# Need to check if valid returnUrl is provided by user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a MVC5 application. There is returnUrl feature which was required for my application. Here is my Login Action with return Url:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    var model = new LoginViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

This is working as expected. When user logs in with return url, he will be navigated to path provided by return url. Now when the return url is not valid or user don't have permission for the specified url, I want user to navigate to dashboard instead. Is there any way to get Action name and controller name based on return url?

I am using Routing along with Attribute routing so I can't split the url into parts and check for valid action as the name can be different due to attribute routing.

Comment: Security: Do validate that the returnUrl is local. ASP.NET (Core) provides the `IsLocalUrl` helper method.

Comment: What if the user navigates to an invalid Url in another way?  Maybe this redirect isn't the place to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for two scenario here.

1. Return url is not valid
2. User don't have permission

For first just check the URL validation as below.

`if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(returnUrl, UriKind.Absolute))`

For second let it redirect and as default behavior application will redirect again to appropriate dashboard page if user does not have permission to access returnUrl
(Read 'S' from SOLID principles)

Comment: `if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(returnUrl, UriKind.Absolute))` will only check if url is valid. But I want to check if it exist in my current application. Means if specific controller and action exists.